# How to get Collections sorted in descending order of their size in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, size, storage

I need the size of all collections in a MongoDB sorted in their descending order of size along with their storage size.

Sample output :

```
admin.system.users: 2717 (36864)
admin.system.keys: 170 (16384)
admin.system.version: 104 (16384)
```

Can someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

Voila:

```
mongos> var s=[];db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(n){ s.push(db[n].stats()); });s=s.sort(function(a,b){return b['size']-a['size']});for(var c in s){print(s[c]['ns']+" "+s[c]['size']+" ("+s[c]['storageSize']+") " ); }
test.test1 75682763 (11538432) 
test.data 736 (32768)
```

mongos>

Comment: Thanks for the update.
The code is working fine but it is returning a lengthy output.
What I want to print is 
"collectname||size||storagesize" only and nothing else.